# New-ADUser Access denied error with Powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-remoting

When I run .ps1 I have written to create AD accounts and Mailboxes based on arguments passed to it from a WinForm I am consistently getting the error:

> New-ADUser  : Access is denied

The script is run when someone clicks a button in a winform and below is the command the button issues:

```
Powershell.exe "C:\Users\admin\Scripts\usercreationscript.ps1" -department 'Accounting - North America' -GivenName 'test' -Surname 'testlast' -path 'OU=users,DC=domain1,DC=com' -Title 'Sys Admin' -Office 'NJ' -StreetAddress '123 ST' -City 'Moorestown' -PostalCode '08057' -State 'NJ' -Manager 'Jacobb' -MercuryFlag 0 -MirroredUser 'jacobb' -username 'test.testlast'
```

I have set the execution policy on the remote servers to `unrestricted` and have also run the `Enable-PSRemoting` command. The credentials that I supply when prompted are domain administrator credentials. I have also set the trusted hosts to *

When I open the script in Powershell ISE I can connect to remote servers with the `Enter-PSSession` command I have in the script and can successfully create AD accounts.

I am at a loss as to what is causing the issue.

Full script:

```
param( [string]$username, [string]$department, [string]$GivenName, [string]$Surname, [string]$path, [string]$Title, [string]$Office, [string]$StreetAddress, [string]$City, [string]$PostalCode, [string]$State, [string]$Manager, [string]$MercuryFlag, [string]$MirroredUser)

If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{   
#"No Administrative rights, it will display a popup window asking user for    Admin rights"

$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process "$psHome\powershell.exe" -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments

break
}
#"After user clicked Yes on the popup, your file will be reopened with Admin rights"
#"Put your code here"


#region - Required Functions - ONLY MODIFY AFTER BACKING UP COPY OF SCRIPT


function connect-Domain1AD {
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DC1.domain1.com -Credential $Credentialdomain1
}
function Connect-Domain1Exchange {
$domain1session = New-PSSession -Authentication Kerberos -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 'http://exchange1.domain1.com/Powershell'  -Credential $Credentialdomain1
Import-PSSession $domain1session
}
function Connect-Domain2Exchange {
$session = New-PSSession -Authentication Kerberos -ConnectionUri 'http://exchange1.domain2.com/Powershell'  -Credential $Credentialdomain2
Enter-PSSession $Session
}
function Connect-Domain2AD {
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Dc1.domain2.com -Credential $Credentialdomain2
}
function New-Domain2User{
$userroot ="\\arizona\RemoteAppProfiles\$USERNAME"
New-ADUser `
        -name ($givenname + " " + $surname) `
        -SamAccountName $Username `
        -department $department `
        -Title $title  `
        -office $office `
        -StreetAddress $street `
        -city $city `
        -State $state `
        -PostalCode $PostalCode `
        -path "OU=users,DC=domain2,DC=com" `
        -GivenName $GivenName `
        -Surname $Surname `
        -DisplayName ($givenname + " " + $surname) `
        -userPrincipalName ($username + "@domain2.com") `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "A temp password." -AsPlainText -force) `
        -Enabled $true `
        -PasswordNeverExpires $true `
        -CannotChangePassword $false `
        -ProfilePath \\arizona\RemoteAppProfiles\$Username\ `
        -HomeDrive U: `
        -HomeDirectory $userroot
Set-ADUser $USERNAME -Add @{extensionattribute14=$username}  
}
function New-Domain1User {
New-aduser -name ($givenname + " " + $surname) `
        -GivenName $givenname `
        -Surname $surname `
        -DisplayName ($givenname + " " + $surname) `
        -SamAccountName $Username `
        -userPrincipalName ($username + "@goevo.com") `
        -path $path `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "A temp password." -AsPlainText -force) `
        -Enabled $true `
        -PasswordNeverExpires $false `
        -CannotChangePassword $false `
        -department $department `
        -Title $title `
        -office $office `
        -StreetAddress $street `
        -city $city `
        -State $state `
        -PostalCode $zipcode `
        -Manager $Manager
 }
function New-Domain1Mailbox {
Enable-mailbox -identity $username 
Set-Mailbox -identity $username `
    -customAttribute1 "Domain1" `
    -customAttribute2 "user" `
    -customAttribute3 "Internal" `
    -customAttribute5 $office `
    -customattribute6 $department `
    -customattribute7 $ca7 `
    -customattribute8 $ca8
    }

#endregion - Required Functions

Write-Host $MercuryFlag


If($MercuryFlag -eq '1' ){

Set-variable -name Credentialdomain2 -value $Host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need Domain2 credentials", "Please enter your Domain2 user name and password:", "", "Domain2.com") -scope global
Connect-Domain2AD 
import-module activedirectory
New-Domain2User
Exit-PSSession
get-pssession | remove-pssession 

Set-variable -name Credentialdomain1 -value $Host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need Domain1 credentials", "Please enter your Domain1 user name and password:", "", "Domain1.com") -scope global
connect-Domain1AD
New-Domain1User
Exit-PSSession
get-pssession | remove-pssession
Connect-Domain1Exchange
New-Domain1Mailbox
Exit-PSSession
get-pssession | remove-pssession 
}
else {
Set-variable -name Credentialdomain1 -value $Host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need Domain1 credentials", "Please enter your Domain1 user name and password:", "", "Domain1.com") -scope global
connect-Domain1AD
New-Domain1User
Exit-PSSession
get-pssession | remove-pssession
Connect-Domain1Exchange
New-Domain1Mailbox
Exit-PSSession
get-pssession | remove-pssession  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing
:

```
function connect-Domain1AD {
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DC1.domain1.com -Credential $Credentialdomain1
}
```

to

```
function connect-Domain1AD {
$domain1ad = new-pssession -ComputerName DC1.domain1.com -Credential $Credentialdomain1
Invoke-Command –Session $domain1ad –ScriptBlock {Import-Module ActiveDir*}
Import-PSSession –Session $domain1ad –Module ActiveDir* -AllowClobber
}
```